# Do I need to create an additional index including _id when sharding a MongoDB collection

Tags: mongodb, sharding

My collection has an organization-id `oid` field which I would like to use for my hashed shard-key. When doing so, I should include an `oid` filter in all of my queries for this collection.

**Question**: Do I also need to create an `{ oid: 1, _id: 1 }` index in order to effectively query individual entries or is the default index `_id` somehow used here since all `oid` related entries should be part of the same node?

I don't fully understand the role of the default `_id` index in a sharded collection. I've only found info about the [uniqueness of the `_id` index for a sharded collection](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/sharding-shard-key/#unique-indexes) and it seems like each shard holds it's own `_id` index.

Comment: No, the "shard" key is used to divide documents into different shards (instances/servers) at that point each instance maintains it's own index tree for the "real" indexes.

Comment: You are using "Hashed Sharding".  You can use a compound hashed index as a Shard Key (v.4.4+). The linked article in your question post is for "Ranged Sharding". Your shard key is for even data distribution and efficient and targeted queries.